# Generalize discrete Lyapunov equation for n-th order linear dynamics system

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

My specific application is analysis of dynamic textures using linear dynamics systems of the form

$$
I(t) = Cz(t) + w(t) \\
z(t + 1) = Az(t) + Bv(t),
$$

where $I(t)$ is the original signal, $z(t)$ is its low-dimensional representation, and $C$ is the orthogonal basis for the subspace. For comparing two systems, the discrete Lyapunov equation can be used, taking the form

$$
\mathcal{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & \textbf{0} \\
\textbf{0} & A_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathcal{Q} = \big[C_1 C_2\big]^T\big[C_1 C_2\big]
$$
$$
\mathcal{A}\mathcal{X}\mathcal{A}^T - \mathcal{X} + \mathcal{Q} = 0.
$$

However, this only works for first-order systems; that is, systems which for $z(t + 1)$, only the previous time point $z(t)$ is required. **How can I generalize this formulation to work for n-th order systems**, e.g. $z(t + 1) \approx A_1z(t) + A_2z(t - 1) + ... + A_dz(t - d + 1)$?

Just to clarify: in the definition of $\mathcal{A}$, the terms $A_1$ and $A_2$ are meant to refer to $A$ from system 1 and system 2, respectively. In the approximation of n-th order $z(t + 1)$, the terms $A_1$ through $A_d$ all belong to **one system**; thus, comparing multiple systems would somehow involve comparing the $d$ parameters $A$ that each separately defines. How exactly that could be done is the question I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment your states as the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix} z(t+1) \\ z(t) \\ z(t-1) \\ \vdots \\ z(t-d+2) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2 & \dots & A_{d-1} & A_d \\ I & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & I & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & I & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} z(t) \\ z(t-1) \\ z(t-2) \\ \vdots \\ z(t-d+1) \end{bmatrix}$$

Then, you get $\tilde{z}(t+1) = \tilde{A} \tilde{z}(t)$.

Comment: Perfect! It makes perfect sense; I suppose it's one of those things I should have known. Thanks!

Comment: I know it's been a few months, but I have another question: the standard discrete [Lyapunov equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) specify that $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{X}$, and $\mathcal{Q}$ are all $\in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$; however, the new definition of $\tilde{A}$ changes the dimensionality of the equations; how does $\mathcal{Q}$ change?

Comment: Nevermind--got it the same way as $\tilde{A}$, in the form of $\tilde{C}$, or just a matrix with $C$ repeated $d$ times along its diagonal.